# CoreBluetooth Pairing To Lego NXT

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I am trying to use Apple's CoreBluetooth framework to connect an iPhone or iPod Touch to a Lego NXT. However, it does not seem like there is any documentation from Apple about this framework at all. Does anyone know how to use it? What the available methods/objects are? Or in general just how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreBluetooth provides APIs only for interacting with new Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) devices.  This is a new standard that is not compatible with traditional Bluetooth.  The iPhone 4S has a dual mode BT chip that does LE and regular mode.  So you will not be able to use CoreBluetooth to talk to traditional Bluetooth devices like NXT.  However, in the future it would make sense for applications like NXT to use LE mode Bluetooth.

Comment: What can I use then to actually interact with traditional bluetooth devices? Is there an api somewhere that I can use to accomplish this? My next option if not is to use iPhone wifi, send to a computer over wifi, and then the computer communicate to the NXT over its bluetooth. However, I would like to eliminate that middle-man if possible

Comment: Apple has traditionally been very closed about apps using Bluetooth.  There are no public APIs for talking to arbitrary BT devices from an iphone.  You could use android, or wifi as you described.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 - The External Accessory framework provides communication capabilities for talking with non-LE Bluetooth devices, but those devices need to be in the MFi program and designed for use with iOS. This is not for communication with generic Bluetooth hardware like that in the NXT, so you're out of luck from that angle. You might be able to do something on a jailbroken device, but the WiFi relay is probably your best bet.

Comment: Alright I guess I will have to suggest using wifi relaying. That kind of sucks but whatever. Thankfully this is not specifically my project I am just helping to advise someone else's project. Thanks for all of your assistance guys!